# Getting the CORS error while getting calling the Instagram api

Tags: ember.js, cors, instagram, ember-cli, instagram-api

I have ember app which show Instagram images.I am making the request to Instagram api to user information like profile pic and username but I am getting the error

Error

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=25634653241563.63765274276357. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.example.co.in' is therefore not allowed access.

In the Instagram Manage client I have filled the website as "http://example.co.in"

The Request

```
raw({
        url:"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=25634653241563.63765274276357",
        crossDomain: true,
      }).then(function(response){
      console.log(response)
})
```

Comment: It's a bit difficult to know the best answer for your situation without more info. Will you post the relevant code snippets?

Comment: @PatrickBerkeley I have edited the question more specific thing.I have implemented the login part.

Answer (score 1):

Before calling ajax request you can configure ajax setup settings to allow cross domain origin request..

Ember.$.ajaxSetup({
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true
  });
This will take care of the appending cookie settings to each request.